# Below iphone 7 parameter be nil ,but above are normally functional

Tags: ios, swift

The same code run on below iPhone 7 simulator can not properly get value, but above iPhone 7 can work.

crash this line:

```
connet(str: "https://a_web?code=\(code!)")
```

Error message:

> Thread 1: Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Option

I am sure that it appoint to this parameter code.
VC1 use segue to VC2.

VC1

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if segue.identifier == "loginS" {
        let employeeVC = segue.destination as! EmployeeVC
        employeeVC.code = self.code
    }
}
```

VC2

```
// Error on the following line:
connet(str: "https://a_web?code=\(code!)")   

func connet(str : String){
    if let url = URL(string: str) {
        let safariController = SFSafariViewController(url: url)
        present(safariController, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
}
```

What should I do, can make all device work well?

Comment: It would seem that `code` is `nil` and you are force-unwrapping it which is causing the crash. You need to debug your code and figure out why `code` is `nil` for some devices and not others. No one here can help because you have not provided any details related to how `code` is initialized.

Comment: I can not find why this happened, so ask to find anyone for any possible way.
Thank for you summarize my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pls, try to declare code in EmployeeVC as

```
var code = ""
```

then call method like this

```
connet(str: "https://a_web?code=\(code)")
```

and try to push VC as

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if segue.identifier == "loginS" {
        if let employeeVC = segue.destination as? EmployeeVC {
            employeeVC.code = self.code
        }

    }
}
```

If code is integer then send it as string after parsing it.
thanks